# Stripe Api Getting data from given date

Tags: .net, stripe-payments

How Can I get some data starting from the given Date, is there any query parameter for that just like "starting_after" for pagination??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, there are date filters. For example, if you wanted to search for invoices in dotnet, you can use the "created" filter to find invoices created before or after a given date

```
var filters = new InvoiceListOptions()
{
    Created = new DateRangeOptions
    {
        GreaterThan = startDate,
        LessThanOrEqual = endDate
    }
};
```